# How to break while loop immediately after condition is met (and not run rest of code)?

Tags: python, logic, boolean-logic

I have this dice game made in python for class, I am using functions for the scoring logic (which I believe is all working as desired). I have put these functions in a while loop so that when either player reaches 100 banked score the game ends. However, I cannot get this to work as intended.

```
while int(player1Score) < 100 or int(player2Score) < 100:
    player1()
    player2()
```

Here is one of the functions (the other is the same with score added to player 2's variable and some output changes):

```
def player1():
    global player1Score #global score to reference outside of function
    rTotal = 0 #running total - used when gamble
    
    print("\nPlayer 1 turn!")
    while 1==1:   
        d = diceThrow() #dicethrow output(s)
        diceIndexer(d)
        print(f"Dice 1: {dice1} \nDice 2: {dice2}")
        
        if dice1 == '1' and dice2 == '1': #both die = 1 (banked & running = 0)
            player1Score = 0
            rTotal = 0
            print("DOUBLE ONE! Banked total reset, Player 2's turn.")
            break
            
        elif dice1 == '1' or dice2 == '1': #either die = 1 (running = 0)
            rTotal = 0
            print("Rolled a single one. Player 2's turn!")
            break
                
        else: #normal dice roll - gamble or bank
            choice = input("Gamble (G) or Bank (B): ")
            choice = choice.upper() #incase lowercase letter given
                
            if choice == 'G': #if Gamble chosen - reroll dice & add to running
                rTotal += int(dice1) + int(dice2)
    
            elif choice == 'B': #used to save score.
                rTotal += int(dice1) + int(dice2)
                player1Score += rTotal
                print(f"\nPlayer 1 banked! Total: {player1Score}")
                break
    print("Turn over")
```

I have tried changing the 'or' in the while loop to an 'and'. While that did stop faster, it did not stop exactly as the other player achieved a score higher than 10.

Comment: At least "or" is wrong, "and" is right. I didn't understand the problem with the "and" variant. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MichaelButscher when I have the while loop set as 'or' it waits for both to be above 100 to stop. When 'and' is selected, after player1 reaches more than 100, it stops after player 2's turn, but when player 2 reaches more than 100, it stops as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is inside the function put an if statement (outside of the while) to return a value from the function using `return` like this:

```
def exampleFunction1():
    #scoring logic here
    if bank > finalScore: #Score to reach to win game
        print(f"Score is over {finalScore}!")
        return 0
```

Then inside the while loop, attach the functions to a variable so that the return value could be identified. Use the return value to `break` the while loop:

```
while True: #Breaks as soon as either player gets above 100 score
    x = exampleFunction1()
    if x == 0:
        break
    x = exampleFunction2()
    if x == 0:
        break
```

(Sidenote: I rewrote my whole program to take one `gameLogic()` function and apply this to the different players, but I still used the while loop stated second)

Answer (score 0):

bro.

i read your code but i can't get some points as below.

```html
if dice1 == '1' and dice2 == '1': #both die = 1 (banked & running = 0)
            player1Score = 0
```

the code above makes player1Score as zero.
and there's no adding score code for player2Score.

For this reason, the while loop doesn't stop.
plz, check it first.

Comment: This is a feature, if the person scores a double 1 their total score goes down to 0. And about that, this is the function for player 1 only, I have a second function for player 2 that does this but for player2Score.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean logic works like this.

You want both scores to be less then 100 while the game runs which also means one of the scores should not be 100 or higher.

both scores less then 100

```
int(player1Score) < 100 and int(player2Score) < 100
```

one of the socres is not 100 or higher

```
!int(player1Score) >= 100 or !int(player1Score) >= 100
```

The reason why the game didn't stop when you changed the "or" to "and" is because player1Score and player2Score are being evaluated after both player1() and player2() are called. Even if player1 scored over 100, the game wouldn't stop and the turn would go over to player2, goes into the next loop evaluation and finally stop the loop.

To fix this, change the while loop of both player1() and player() to this.

```
while player1Score < 100:
```

And also add evaluation after calculating scores.

```
else: #normal dice roll - gamble or bank
    choice = input("Gamble (G) or Bank (B): ")
    choice = choice.upper() #incase lowercase letter given
    
    #    rTotal += int(dice1) + int(dice2)
    # rewriting the same code is a bad practice. 
    # In this case, you can just write the same code outside the if-else logic since if-else doesn't effect the code.

    rTotal += int(dice1) + int(dice2)

    if choice == 'G': #if Gamble chosen - reroll dice & add to running
        # added evaluation to stop the game
        if player1Score+rTotal >= 100:
            break
    if choice == 'B': #used to save score.
        player1Score += rTotal
        print(f"\nPlayer 1 banked! Total: {player2Score}")
        break
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but the problem with `while player1Score < 100:` (if you meant I should replace `while 1==1:`) is that the loop breaks so that it goes to the next player's turn. I did my original while loop to `while int(player1Score) < 100 or int(player2Score) < 100:` so that it would loop their turns, in order, till the desired score is reached. The only other solution I see to this is majorly revamping my whole code, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: In that case, use ` while int(player1Score) < 100 or int(player2Score) < 100: ` for both loop. Then even if the loop goes into next player, it will stop right away.